# Можно ли в запросе разместить таблицы последовательно друг за другом?

Tags: access, ms-access

Имеется таблица 1 и  таблица 2 c одинаковым наименованием составом полей.

Можно ли в запросе разместить таблицы последовательно друг за другом (см. скрин)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На скрине у вас `ms-excel` а не `ms-access`. Если вдруг вам потребовалось в `access` выбрать данные из двух таблиц и показать в виде одного результата, то вам в помощью оператор `union all`

Comment: @teran Ексель показал для схематичности... Аксес пока осваиваю.. Не могли бы вы показать на примере как реализовать предложенное вами решение... Спасибо.

Comment: `SELECT 'Табл 1' as tname, * FROM Таблица1 UNION ALL SELECT 'Табл 2' as tname ,* FROM Таблицы2 ORDER BY  tname, id ` как то так, нет аксесса.

Comment: а может [даже так](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-UNION-aa310e10-282b-4693-b6e3-2a2efdd87f1d) `TABLE  [Таблица1] UNION ALL TABLE [Таблица2]`

Comment: @teran Работает..  Наверное оформляйте как ответ...

Comment: ответ оформил :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно для объединения различных выборок с одинаковым набором полей используют операторы `UNION` и `UNION ALL`. Разница между ними заключается в том, что во втором случае в выборке присутствуют абсолютно все результаты, а в первом результаты без дублирования.

Применительно к вашему вопросу можно построить следующий запрос:

```
SELECT 'Табл 1' as tname, * 
FROM Таблица1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Табл 2' as tname, * 
FROM Таблицы2 
ORDER BY tname, id
```

Поскольку `ms-access` обладает несколько специфическим SQL-синтаксисом то также возможен [следующий синтаксис](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-UNION-aa310e10-282b-4693-b6e3-2a2efdd87f1d) для полного объединения таблицы без фильтрации результатов:

```
TABLE [Таблица1] 
UNION ALL 
TABLE [Таблица2]
```